# Aligning navigation menu in visual basic

Tags: html, css, vb.net, navigation

Here's my full code. I haven't modify my default css code. Does anyone know how to align nav bar to the right next to the logo? Please note I am currently learning visual basic web application building and my knowledge is very limited on this area.

thanks

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="default.aspx.vb" Inherits="Wiltshire_mobile._default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            font-size: large;
        }
        .style2
        {
            text-align: right;
        }
        .style3
        {
            width: 162px;
            height: 83px;
            border-width: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="style2">
        <asp:Button ID="mysiteloginbutton1" runat="server" Text="My Site Login" BackColor="#FF9900"
            ForeColor="White" Style="text-align: right" /> &nbsp;<span class="style1"><strong 
            style="text-align: left"><a 
            href="#">Sign up</a> | <a href="#">Help</a> |<asp:DropDownList 
            ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
            <asp:ListItem>English</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Bangla</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="http://www.wiltshire-mobile.com">
            <img alt="Wiltshire mobile website logo" class="style3" src="Images/logo.PNG" /></a> <span class="style1"><strong 
            style="text-align: left">
            <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" StaticSubMenuIndent="16px">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Home" Value="Home"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Features" Value="Features"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Tour" Value="Tour"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Plans" Value="Plans"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Blog" Value="Blog"></asp:MenuItem>
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
            </strong></span>
            <br />
            <br />
            Mobile image
            <br />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: All the positioning will be done in your css file.  let me see what I can do to break it all down for you.  You want the menu on the right of the content and your logo above the menu?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are trying to accomplish:

```
<body>
    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr valign="middle">
            <td colspan="2">
                <span style="font-size: 16pt; font-family: Verdana">
                    <a href="http://www.wiltshire-mobile.com">
                        <img alt="Wiltshire mobile website logo" class="style3" src="Images/logo.PNG" /></a> <span class="style1"><strong style="text-align: left">
                </span>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 80%">

            </td>
       </tr>
       <tr valign="top">
            <td style="width: 20%">
                <asp:Button ID="mysiteloginbutton1" runat="server" Text="My Site Login" BackColor="#FF9900" ForeColor="White" Style="text-align: right" /> &nbsp;<span class="style1"><strong style="text-align: left"><a href="#">Sign up</a> | <a href="#">Help</a> |<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                <asp:ListItem>English</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Bangla</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
           </td>
           <td style="width: 80%">
                <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" StaticSubMenuIndent="16px">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Home" Value="Home"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Features" Value="Features"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Tour" Value="Tour"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Plans" Value="Plans"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Blog" Value="Blog"></asp:MenuItem>
                    </Items>
               </asp:Menu>
          <br />
          <br />
          @RenderBody
          <br />
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Now, I added '@RenderBody', as this should be used as your "_LayoutPage" and then each page calls to this to show how it should be designed.

The basic concept is to design the site as a table and then separate each element into columns and rows of that table, as I did here.  `<td>` and `<tr>` are used to separate these items.

If you wanted to go more into how things looked, you should have this page point to your site.css file.  The css file should contain everything as it is regarded to positioning of text, color, layout for specific items (such as tables), etc.  Hope this helps.